# Spring Boot 3.0.3 and wildfly 25.0.1

Tags: spring-boot, wildfly-25

My spring boot application run on the embedded Tomcat and if i try to reach this rest service

[image]

all it's fine.
When i try to deploy on wildfly 25 i try to reach the same service but happens this:

[image]

I tried to do a lot of thinf but still nothing.

Here more details:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>xxxxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxxx</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>name</name>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        
    </properties>





        <profile>
              <id>devserver</id>
              <properties>
                 <activatedProperties>devserver</activatedProperties>
              </properties>
            
            
            <dependencies>
                
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency> 
                
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                    <scope>provided</scope> 
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
                        </exclusion> 
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                        </exclusion> 
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                        </exclusion> 
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                         </exclusion>
                        
                    </exclusions> 
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions> 
                </dependency>
                
                 <!--<dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>-->
                
                
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.annotation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-annotations-api_1.3_spec</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
                </dependency>

        
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.12.Final</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>

         
                 <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                
                
                <!-- spring-boot 3 --> 
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <version>6.0.0</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
                    <version>3.15.3.Final</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                    <artifactId>resteasy-multipart-provider</artifactId>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                    <version>4.7.4.Final</version>
                </dependency>
                
                
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                    <version>2.19.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                  <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                  <version>2.19.0</version>
                </dependency>
                
                <!-- spring-boot 3 --> 
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </dependency>

                <!-- spring-boot 3 --> 
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.1</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>

                <!-- spring-boot 3 --> 
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
                    <version>10.0.0</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
                
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </dependency>
                
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.1.1</version>
                </dependency>

                
            
                
            </dependencies>
            
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.3.2</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                            <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                    <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                                </manifest>
                                <manifestEntries>
                                    <Implementation-Build>${buildNumber}</Implementation-Build>
                                </manifestEntries>
                            </archive>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>4.0.0.Final</version> 
        
                        <configuration>
                            <filename>${project.build.finalName}.war</filename>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    
                    <plugin>
                         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                         <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                         <version>2.19.1</version>
                         <configuration>
                            <systemPropertyVariables>
                                <org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem>
                                    org.springframework.boot.logging.log4j2.Log4J2LoggingSystem
                                </org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingSystem>
                            </systemPropertyVariables>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>   
                </plugins>
            </build> 
        </profile>
```

jboss-web.xml
[image]

I am new in spring and even I have to use wildfly, I cannot use Tomcat.

Can you help me? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Boot 3 requires Jakarta EE 9 or later. WildFly 25, unless you're using the Jakarta EE 9.1 preview distribution, only supports Jakarta EE 8. If you want to use Spring Boot 3.0 and you must use Wildfly, you'll either have to use the EE 9.1 preview distribution of Wildfly 25 or upgrade to Wildfly 27 [which supports Jakarta EE 10](https://www.wildfly.org/news/2022/11/09/WildFly27-Final-Released/). Alternatively, you could stick with Spring Boot 2.7 which requires Jakarta EE 8.

Comment: Really thank you for helping me. This was helpfull, works fine with wildfly 27.